# Proving that this equation represents a circle.

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to prove that the set of $z$ that satisfies the following equation represents a circle or a straight line on $\mathbb C$.

$$(a\bar c-c\bar a)|w^2|+(a\bar d-c\bar b)w+(b\bar c-d\bar a)\bar w+b\bar d-d\bar b=0  $$
If $(a\bar c-c\bar a)=0$, I could prove that this is a straight line. (It took very long though. If you know how to show it simply, please give me some ideas on how to proceed.)

Apparently, if $(a\bar c-c\bar a)\neq 0$, we can get
$$\Bigg |\displaystyle w+\frac{\bar a d-\bar c b}{\bar a c-\bar c a}\Bigg|=\Bigg |\frac{ad-bc}{\bar a c-\bar c a}\Bigg |.$$But I don't know how it works. I tried to factorize the first equation, but it didn't work. So I tried to expand the second equation by replacing the absolute value with the conjugate, but it didn't give me any good idea. Could someone give me some clues?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the numbers into exponential form, then see if you can use the exponential definitions of the trig functions to reduce it to something that looks like $sin^2(k)+cos^2(l)=|z|/s$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a\bar c-c\bar a)|w^2|+(a\bar d-c\bar b)w+(b\bar c-d\bar a)\bar w+b\bar d-d\bar b=0$$

Dividing by $a\bar c-c\bar a$ you get

$$w \bar w + \frac{a\bar d-c\bar b}{a\bar c-c\bar a}w+ \frac{b\bar c-d\bar a}{a\bar c-c\bar a}\bar w=-\frac{b\bar d-d\bar b}{a\bar c-c\bar a}$$

Now, note that

$$\overline{b\bar c-d\bar a}=-(a\bar d-c\bar b)$$
and
$$\overline{a\bar c-c\bar a}=-(a\bar c-c\bar a)$$

Thus

$$\frac{b\bar c-d\bar a}{a\bar c-c\bar a}=\overline{\left( \frac{a\bar d-c\bar b}{a\bar c-c\bar a}\right)} \,.$$

For simplicity, let $z:= \frac{a\bar d-c\bar b}{a\bar c-c\bar a}$. Then, your equation is

$$w \bar w + zw+\overline{z} \bar w=-\frac{b\bar d-d\bar b}{a\bar c-c\bar a}$$

Adding $z \bar z$ yields

$$$w \bar w + zw+\overline{z} \bar w +z \bar z =-\frac{b\bar d-d\bar b}{a\bar c-c\bar a} + z \bar z $$

or

$$(w+\bar z)(\bar w +z)= -\frac{b\bar d-d\bar b}{a\bar c-c\bar a} + z \bar z$$

You should be able to finish from here.